# Datatables.How can i get number of the current page inside the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#users-data-table').DataTable();
        var info = table.page.info();
        $('#users-data-table').DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '@(Url.Action("GetFilterUsers", "Users", new { area = "Admin" }))?pageNumber=1' + info.page,
                type: "GET"
            }
        });
    });
```

its not working because I can't initialize `$('#users-data-table').DataTable();` twice.
How can I get number of the current page inside `DataTable` ?

Comment: You need to initialize the datatable once: var oTable = $('#users-data-table').DataTable(); and than use the 'oTable' variable to refer to it.

Comment: How can I set  "serverSide: true" and "ajax:{...}" via  oTable?

Answer (score 1):

I mean You must initialize it only once:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#users-data-table').DataTable({

         serverSide: true,
         ajax: {
               //your code
         }

    });
});
```

Comment: How can I get number of the current page inside ajax?

Comment: As you have done in your code. Ajax url accept also php variables.